# Nginx rewrite rule for specific regex pattern

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to rewrite the following url in NGINX:

https://example.com/ab12-cdef4567?c=123

Into this:

https://example.com/ab12-cdef4567.php?c=123

The pattern will always be {4 alphanumeric}-{8 alphanumeric}

This is what I am attempting without success:

```
rewrite ^/(.{4}-.{8})?(.*)$ /$1.php?$2 last;
```

Comment: Does any of the below answers help? Please do let me know if you need something else in regards to this post.

Answer (score 4):

You may try:

```
^(.*)(\w{4}-\w{8})(.*)$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of line respectively.
- **`(.*)`** - Represents first capturing group matching everything before alphanumeric pattern string.
- **`(\w{4}-\w{8})`** - Represents second capturing group matching the required alphnumeric pattern. If you do not want to include `_` then you can assign them manually; something like `[0-9A-Za-z]`.
- **`(.*)`** - Represents third capturing group matching everything after alphanumeric pattern string.
- **`$1$2.php$3`** - For the replacement part; you can use the first, second and 3rd capturing group along with `.php` extension.

---

[image: Pictorial Representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/jq033m/2)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match the query string (`?c=123`) using `rewrite`. Nginx uses a normalised URI when matching `location` and `rewrite` statements, which has the query string removed.

The `rewrite` directive will append the original query string to the resulting URI unless the replacement string ends with a `?`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

For example:

```
rewrite "^(/.{4}-.{8})$" $1.php last;
```

The entire regular expression needs to be in quotes because of the braces.